# How to define the entityId in Orion

Tags: fiware-orion

I have to use Orion (NGSI v2), and I have a question about the name of entityId of my context;

could I use a simple ID or URN (like NGSI-LD spec)?

What is the best practice?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better to use URIs for your entities, your path to Linked Data will be smoother. The problem with table names should be fixed by the data storage component for instance by calculating a hash of the URI and converting it to the proper alphabet supported by the database concerning table names ...

Comment: Does some data storage GE in the FIWARE ecosystem that kind of hashing for URIs?

Comment: I am not aware but it would be a good idea IMHO, ensure table names are not broken if ids are URIs ...

Comment: In general "hashing" table ids is not a good idea since it hides important information. In this case to which entity the table belongs to.

Answer (score 2):

From a NGSIv2 point of view, any entity ID that complies with the [identifiers syntax restrictions](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/doc/manuals/orion-api.md#identifiers-syntax-restrictions) is valid.

Having said this, in general the simpler entity ID, the better from an integration point of view. For instance, if you are persisting context data using Cygnus sink for PostgreSQL, note that PostGresSQL could use tables which name includes the entity ID (for instance, if the `dm-by-entity-database-schema` DM is used, see [this reference](https://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cygnus-ngsi/flume_extensions_catalogue/ngsi_postgresql_sink.html#section1.2)).

Thus, better to use simple entity IDs than URN-like entity IDs, from my point of view.